# jqgrid how to persist row when reloading grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Some info of the situation:

Say I have a grid view of 10 rows (bec of fix height), but my data record has more than 10 records - so there will be a vertical scrollbar.

say I want to edit (or delete) row 14,16 and 17.
when selecting row 14, I use the onselect function to call out a external form.
Once the external form is submitted, the data is saved and I update the grid by doing a trigger reloadgrid. [I didnt use the editform that comes with jqgrid bec I want to change data from other tables relating to the edited records too.]

At this juncture (reloadinggrid), the whole grid will refresh and move back to the 1st row.
I will then have to scroll down to row 16 and click on it. This continues for subsequent records further down...

Was wondering if there is any means of causing the grid to refresh with the latest updated data, AND yet not go back to the first row BUT continues at the row number in which we are viewing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a specific need to reload the grid. Jqgrid by default puts the edited row on edit or removes the deleted row from the grid on delete. So all what is required is to set the reload grid to false. On edit/delete the information is posted to the server and then you can update the database accordingly. On success the grid itself replaces the content without reloading the content.

If reload grid is called by default it replaces the entire content and hence the control goes to the top first row.

Reloading the grid is desirable when you are inserting a new row in the database and you need the database primary key in the grid.

Comment: Bec the grid serves only as a reference look-up to other data. Kind of space constrain so didn't have the grid shows every fields. Instead I use an external form to update the data and uses ajax to have the data saved. Doing by that method, the grid cell is not being updated. So in order to update the cells, I did a reload, which pulls data from the updated database. Currently I am toying with setSelection. I keep the rowid in mind, then after reloading, I do a setSelection to the row, that kind of help. but wonders if there is other better ways.

Comment: You can go for the form edit then. set hidden=true for all grid columns which you dont want to show in UI, but also set editable = true. This way when you open a form to edit a particular row, you see all the editable contents in the form .

Comment: This alternative is possible though I didn't give it a try - bec it will involved many changes to the existing code. But in theory it is possible. the data will get updated without having to refresh the grid. Thus maintaining the row and having the row of info updated. Likely will try this only when going to top records becomes so unbearable. Thanks for the suggestion.